# Import an RDATA, SPSS, SAS, or STATA file into Mathematica

Tags: import

I would like to import the [World Value Survey](http://www.worldvaluessurvey.org/index_html) data file into Mathematica, but it's only given in spss, sas or stata formats, which are statistical analysis softwares format I think.

I can't get to import these files in Mathematica, they are not recognized.

I've found a [Wolfram executable](http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/MathSource/7808/) that should allow me to import SAS files but it can't make it work on Linux. Have you already been able to import such files in Mathematica?

Comment: No luck so far. I have submitted the data file to Wolfram|Alpha, I think it would be a great addition to their search engine.

Comment: http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/sas7bdat/vignettes/sas7bdat.pdf has some information on reverse enginerring the sas7bdat binary format if you want to do any tinkering with `BinaryReadList`. Looks pretty horrible though. If you can get hold of a .dta file, according to [this](http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/256784) you can use RLink and get R to do the import for you first.

Comment: @rhermans Which file exactly would you like to import? Could you edit the original question and add a direct link to it? What should be in the file?

Comment: @rhermans The data (at least what I found on that website) is also available in R (labeled "rdata").  R is free and can be called from Mathematica.  Also with R you can import data from SPSS and some versions of Stata (and SAS as is mentioned above).

Comment: @MarcoB As in the original question, the idea was to get the data from  World Value Survey, in any of the forms available in the Longitudinal Data Files, i.e R, SAS, SATA, SPSS, but I would not discard retrieving particular variables directly from the web.

Comment: @JimBaldwin I was expecting reading the file directly, but I guess R is a free alternative, that may simplify things.

Comment: Its frankly bizzare that the data dictionary is available in excel but the actual data isn't - at least it would be more universal than any of the other formats..  Have you tried mailing them and suggesting supporting at least one non-proprietary format should be strongly considered?

Comment: Looks like the quickest way is to download R and use this [code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13189467/how-to-convert-rdata-format-into-text-file-format) here to export to CSV.  Since you only need to do it as a once off there is very little point in messing around with Rlink.

Comment: @GordonCoale R is bundled with Mathematica and can be called with the RLink package.

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries Good point which I didn't know.  Although being pedantic on 10.1 at least MMA has to download the r paclet from WRI the first time `InstallR` is called, and its a pretty chunky download :)  Atleast its all automated.  I wouldn't run vanilla R without R studio personally.

Comment: @GordonCoale, I would give the bounty to youror similar R-based solution if formatted as an answer.

Comment: @rhermans - working on it but never used Rlink before ;)

Answer (score 14):

This should do the trick - disclaimer the file is 1.4Gb so everything takes a veerryyy long time on my MacBook air, and you will need an active internet connection for `InstallR` to work.  Note you have to escape `\` internal R file paths and anything else that uses a double quote.

Firstly download the rdata version of the file from the link given.

```
Needs["RLink`"];

InstallR[];

REvaluate[
"load(\"~/Downloads/WVS_Longitudinal_1981_2014_R_v2015_04_18.rdata\"\)"];

(*{".Traceback","WVS_Longitudinal_1981_2014_R_v2015_04_18"}*)
```

Writes the data into an R Dataset called WVS_Longitudinal_1981_2014_R_v2015_04_18

```
REvaluate["write.csv(WVS_Longitudinal_1981_2014_R_v2015_04_18,file=\
"WVS_data_rlink.csv\")"];
```

Writes the data back out to a CSV.  Note in this case the file is a simple tabular one.  This might be more problematic for some of the more complex data structures that .rdata format permits.

Theoreticall you can actually import the WVS_Longitudinal_1981_2014_R_v2015_04_18 data directly into MMA and work with it natively from that point but requires me working through the rLink tutorial a bit more than I have time for right now. :)

**EDIT :** Some useful tips to explore the data directly.

Get Column Names

```
REvaluate["names(WVS_Longitudinal_1981_2014_R_v2015_04_18)"] // Short
```

Get a single column in this case S001

```
REvaluate["WVS_Longitudinal_1981_2014_R_v2015_04_18$S001"]
```

Get the first 10 lines of the R data.frame  note the R data objects in there.  `head` is like the unix head not `Head[]`  This data is so wide and deep its hard to get it in a readable format without subsetting and slicing and dicing.

```
REvaluate["head(WVS_Longitudinal_1981_2014_R_v2015_04_18,n=10)"]
```

Answer (score 10):

You are right - those formats are for statistical software packages.

I've noticed in Big Data discussions that **Mathematica** does not want to extend the range of acceptable data formats leaving the job to third-party software.
I would recommend to use software like ['Stat/Transfer'](http://www.stattransfer.com/), which is a usual practice for such tasks.
If you take data from [WVS](http://www.worldvaluessurvey.org/WVSDocumentationWVL.jsp), say Stata's `.dta` which I prefer, you may easily transfer it to **`.CSV`** or **`.DAT`** file. 
Just take an option `ASCII - Delimited` as shown below.
[image]
Then `.csv` is imported to **Mathematica** as [usual](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/ImportingAndExportingData.html).

Another option is to use `ASCII Fixed Format + All Programs` which will produce `.dat` file also easily imported to **Mathematica** (I've checked both cases).

Comment: Thanks for the answer,  'Stat/Transfer' unfortunately its a paid software.

Comment: I'm not aware about free analogs, indeed - it is very specific stuff and works fine.

Answer (score 7):

With the ability to connect to Python I found this snippet of code helpful.  It imports a STATA .dta file using pandas and then outputs it as a Wolfram Dataset.

```
     importDTAMP[fileName_] := Module[{}, 
 python37 = 
       StartExternalSession[<|"System" -> "Python", "Version" -> "3.7.3"|>];
      pythonFileName = StringReplace[fileName, "\\" -> "/"];
      
      ds = ExternalEvaluate[
        python37,
        "
         import pandas as pd;
         path = '" <> pythonFileName <> "';
         df = pd.read_stata(path);
         df
         "
        ];
      
      DeleteObject[python37];
      ds
      
      ]
```